# Phonegap external links have stopped working in testflight only

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

Got an app, it's been fine for over a year. Suddenly external links have stopped working.

**It only breaks in Test flight + Live**

If I run it through the Phonegap Dev app, local browser or even when you run direct from XCode it works perfectly.

Example links i've tried

```
<a href="https://somewebsite.com/terms-conditions" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank','location=yes'); return false;">terms and conditions</a>

<a href="https://somewebsite.com/terms-conditions" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_system','location=yes'); return false;">terms and conditions</a>

<a href="https://somewebsite.com/terms-conditions" target="_blank">terms and conditions</a>

<a href="https://somewebsite.com/terms-conditions" target="_system">terms and conditions</a>
```

In the config.xml

```
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://somewebsite.com/*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
```

Sometimes the link will open but it will take 10+ presses before it does.
Using Phonegap 8.2.2, iOS + Desktop Only, Both at the latest build version and Framework 7.

I've even modified the CDVUIWebViewDelegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request.URL];

    if([url containsString:@"https:"] || [url containsString:@"http:"]){
        if([url containsString:@"somewebsite."] && [url containsString:@".com/terms-conditions"])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once Update your plugin [`cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) after moving to testflight and test it.

Comment: I'm not using inappbrowser and it hasn't been updated since 2018. This issue only started about a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the plugin [`cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) .

This is due to some updated iOS policy, use this and solve your problem :)

Comment: It did not solve my problem and was last updated in 2018. The problem only started a month ago.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, i did. It didn't work originally when i tried it either - that's why i added my own code for handling the the navigation event

Comment: Post the inappbrowser code you used and the error message